# How do I handle interviews nicely if I don't like HR?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

In my country, it is common culture for HR to be insulting. They will ask illegal questions. They will make you jump through hoops, not to prove your skill, but to prove you really want the job.

The reason is because they get hundreds, if not thousands of applications, but the [majority of those applications are seriously unqualified](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FindingGreatDevelopers.html). However, this makes them arrogant. They claim this arrogance as a way to filter out resume spammers.

I know the company itself is quite good. And I know the HR are actually nice people. They were somehow trained to be arrogant, simply because "bigger companies are like that."

One of my pet peeves are interviews that ask completely irrelevant questions like "If you were an animal, what kind of animal would you be?" and an hour long exam with pointless questions like "Translate this long binary number into decimal."

I'm fully qualified for the job, and it's simply a screening interview to see that I'm not crazy. But dumb and illegal questions tend to trigger me into looking mean and crazy.

Comment: As a curiosity: what country are we talking about ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but how can YOU know that you are fully qualified for the job? This sounds kinda arrogant aswell. And the seconds thing: What profession are we talking about? If we are talking about computerscience field, the test task "Translate this 'long' binary number into decimal." is much, but for sure not pointless(except the wording by itself could be phrased in a way of not disvaluing itself).

Comment: What is an illegal question? And are those really actual questions you've had?

Comment: @HorusKol In the country that I work it's illegal to ask questions related to family planning like "Do you plan on having children any time soon?", because they could figure out if you're planning on maternity leave in the near future.

Comment: @Alex - I meant to ask "what is an example of an illegal question" - because the OP hasn't provided any that they have been asked

Comment: *"dumb and illegal questions tend to trigger me into looking mean and crazy."* then the HR people are doing their jobs right. If you get hired, you will sometimes have to work with clients or colleagues who ask dumb or even illegal questions - if you can't act professional then, you're *not* fully qualified for the job...

Comment: In some countries you are allowed to lie when illegal questions come up, and this cannot be held against you. So for "do you plan on having children any time soon" the answer would be "NO" whether true or not.

Comment: Illegal questions are often things that violate things like NDAs or labor/discrimination laws. Usually they realize that it's illegal to ask these things, but do it anyway because "some bigger companies do it". In my country, it is also common for "big companies" to give prostitutes to decision makers to seal a contract, so I suppose some people do want to screen potential employees to see whether they will close one eye.

Comment: Nobody pays me enough to insult me. I do not care about the local culture, as I have already too many years under my belt, international experience to boot and valuable skills. Nobody has the right to be rude to be, and much less in a setting that is no more, no less than a business negotiation. Do no sell yourself short, do not let useless people like usually HR is walk all over you in a power trip. HR people is the face of a place, and I do not want to work in a place that employs idiots.  Last time a woman in HR was rude, I traced her manager in linked.in and complained to him.

Comment: If you are already employed, do not be another yes man. There are plenty of them already.

Comment: @Zaibis I don't know where the OP is from but I can definitely say that there _are_ countries where culture is like described. (I'm from one although I don't live there anymore.) I can't tell if the OP is qualified or not but I had experiences like this before I moved abroad.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I'm not claiming the opposite in anyway. does my comment read so? then sorry

Comment: @Zaibis No, you didi't - I only commented because your first comment appeared to me questioning if the OP was qualified as opposed to HR being rude. Sorry if you didn't mean it that way - I read it like so. I just know that in some countries, you can be well-qualified and HR will still treat you like dirt. It's a combination of rudeness and incompetence on their part.

Comment: What can one say except, "Force yourself to be nice"? If necessary, practice. Lots of people get a friend to pretend to be an interviewer to practice. If your real question is, "Should I be nice?", I'd say "Of course." Unless you're getting a job in the HR department, once you're hired you'll have little contact with these people. So put up with whatever you have to put up with to get the job you want.

Comment: The stance in interviews also varies a lot for the seniority and importance of the position. I was once interviews for a crops of the tops elite Amazon team and they were extra-extra nice all the way long, multiple people in multiple interviews (5 of them)...was also interview for Amazon in another time and another country, some headhunter directed me to an interview that I found out at the last minute was for Helpdesk, and that could not work out of it at the last minute, and the interview was a shitty one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is only one way to deal with this situation:

### Be the professional!

If you have to jump through the hoops to get the job, jump through the hoops.  Prove that you are indeed highly qualified and the best candidate for the job.  It doesn't matter if you dislike HR, that's entirely irrelevant.  If they are the gatekeeper, then do the tasks you are set to the best of your ability or you will find yourself being rejected before you start.

As you say, this is a cultural issue for you.  You can't change it, especially from the outside.  Maintain a high level of professionalism, transcend any negative feelings you have and you can pass through this initial process to get into the more relevant aspects of your application process.

Comment: I'd disagree. There's another way: not applying to places with hostile interviewing atmosphere or shady practices. While initial screening interviews rarely, if ever, are perfect, being asked illegal or inappropriate questions would indicate some other, larger issue within the company.

There's also another aspect to it. As it stands currently, it's the developers who are in shortage, not companies hiring developers. The first step to changing such practices is to stop putting up with them in the first place.

This is not to say you're wrong, but it's certainly not the only way.

Comment: @MaciejGurban According to the OP: `In my country, it is common culture for HR to be insulting.`  It sound systemic where they are.

Comment: @MaciejGurban Just to address your edit, while I agree that you shouldn't put up with it, if you are unemployed and looking for work then you have very little leverage to exact change.  Also there may be a shortage of developers in your location, but it seems not in the OP's given the comment `they get hundreds, if not thousands of applications`.

Comment: While you're right that being unemployed rids the person of a significant leverage, we don't know whether this is OP's situation. I wouldn't go as far as to say that hundreds or thousands of applicants means there isn't a shortage of experienced developers.

Comment: @MaciejGurban Again, I don't disagree.  However, unless HR or the hiring committee goes through every single application they can't tell which ones _are_ the experienced developers in all the noise of unqualified applicants.  Which is kind of the OP's point :)

Comment: Also note: you both are just assuimng that he is a developer. But he didn't said what field he is working in. maybe he is even applying for a job, where there isn't a shortage at all.

Comment: @Zaibis On the contrary.  I'm only using Maciej Gurban's example to counter his point.  Nowhere in my answer do I mention anything about the field as it's entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Thats why I didn't addressed you per se but just added it to be noted ;)

Comment: If all HR behaves like that, then you have no choice : bury your ego and be professional as advised by Jane S. If only some of them behave like that, and others are much more appealing to professionals, OTOH, Maciej Gurban has a point : the latter firms are going to be much more healthy in financial terms, and likely to offer more career development paths due to their success.

Comment: @MaciejGurban I actually started my own company 2 years to avoid dealing with such issues. I actually hold the same stance - avoid shady companies; but unfortunately most of the competent, non shady people move to other countries. I think Jane is right.. I should just suck it up and be professional, since I can't actually change the culture from the outside.

Comment: unfortunately in places with high unemployment and/or a huge pool of people applying for the jobs you just have to suck it in and jump through the hoops smiling.

Comment: @Kilisi Exactly.  If you have no leverage to push with, then there is little you can do but to play the game.

Comment: I myself wouldn't apply to an employer and/or wouldn't stay in an interview with an interviewer whose questions 'crossed the line' for me (while accepting that 'pressure' questions are the norm for senior roles in my industry and allowing for them). However @MaciejGurban not everyone has that luxury for whatever reason. We have to be pragmatic here...

Comment: @Zaibis I assumed that OP is a developer because the link he provided says, verbatim: "Finding Great Developers".